# Can I generate database id-s both serverside and client side with JPA?

Tags: jpa, mariadb, primary-key

I have the following Id description of my entity in JPA:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my_sequence", sequenceName = "my_seq")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "my_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private long id;
```

and it works from Java. Unfortunately, in MariaDB database it is creating, I don't see any column properties about generating ids. I.e. field is not autoincrement. If I add new row to the table with database tool, it says `id` can't be null.

How to configure it to work both client side and server side?

Comment: autoincrement is used for GenerationType.IDENTITY. I never used Sequences for IDs, but in Mariadb they're only available since Version 10.3. Maybe that's your Problem.
If it isn't, maybe this Link is useful: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-identifier-sequence/